# Can we put a border back on the flag dialog?

Tags: feature-request, design

Can we put some sort of border back on the flagging (and close) dialog?

Also the buttons seem very odd..

[image]

Comment: It just needs more red. Flagging is serious business, man. The new design makes it look too mellow. I mean, imagine if the big red button was... black? It would get pushed because it doesn't look important and the world would end swiftly.

Comment: @JoshCaswell whoa... funky. Added that to the OP.

Comment: It should have a drop shadow the same colour as what's in the header indicator. Because that's where it's headed

Comment: @animuson on the contrary, I press big red buttons all the time because they look cool. For some reason they don't let me in the server room anymore

Comment: SO going the microsoft way :(

Comment: You all did click the flag button on this post, just to take a second look at the design, didn't you? ;)

Answer (score 5):

Here is our reasoning for making these changes:

- The use of red in pop-up dialogs usually means "error" or "danger". In the old style, it was being used to mean "you're about to perform a moderator operation". We are making a concerted effort to treat errors more consistently across sites and make non-errors less jarring for the user
- Visually, the border was too thick for the light weight "flat" style of the site
- The old [x] was in the top left, and now it has been moved to the standard top right. We also plan to remove the "cancel" or "close" links from the bottom left in these dialogs to reduce clutter.
- Changes in button styling are intended to make these primary actions more prominent and to address complaints that our old buttons could sometimes be mistaken for being grayed out

Comment: I really miss having *some* differentiation between the close/flag/bounty/... dialog and the rest of the page. One light grey pixel isn't enough.

Comment: It's still got the big ol red border on SE Beta sites

Comment: Wow! 2 hours ago I closed a flag dialogue and thought, how odd that it's on the left.

Comment: Close buttons on the right are not standard for everyone.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I take the point, but I would still submit that the "standard" location is in the top right:  http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/close-button-on-the-left-or-right-side

Comment: If you say "border was too thick for the light weight 'flat' style of the site", what is the rationale behind making buttons black, which – undoubtedly – increases their visual weight? In all normal UIs, buttons *are* grey. Or they have a primary color, like blue/green. They only appear as disabled when the text on them is grey as well or the button is made "flat".

Comment: @slhck Honestly, this was partially an aesthetic choice by Jin, but I supported the decision because I think buttons are an appropriate place to have the added visual weight.